# Swagger UI - Try it Out! Returns whole Swagger Doc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, swagger-ui

When I ran following command :

```
rake swagger:docs
```

It returns me proper JSON files for each controllers.

When I access swagger-ui, it gives me proper page :

[image]

But when I click on Try it Out!, it returns me whole JSON like below :

[image]

I am new to Swagger. Can someone please help me out, where am I going wrong ?

UPDATE : 
My public directory structure :

[image]

UPDATE
trucks.json :

```
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
  "basePath": "http://localhost:3000",
  "resourcePath": "trucks",
  "apis": [
    {
      "path": "/api/v1/trucks.json",
      "operations": [
        {
          "summary": "Fetches all Trucks",
          "parameters": [
            {
              "paramType": "header",
              "name": "X-Auth-Token",
              "type": "string",
              "description": "Authentication Token",
              "required": true
            }
          ],
          "responseMessages": [
            {
              "code": 401,
              "responseModel": null,
              "message": "Unauthorized"
            },
            {
              "code": 406,
              "responseModel": null,
              "message": "The request you made is not acceptable"
            }
          ],
          "nickname": "API::V1::Trucks#index",
          "method": "get"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "authorizations": null
}
```

Comment: What's the expected behavior?

Comment: Could it be that the structure of the directories in `public` where your Swagger JSON is stored is the same as the route that you are trying to access?

Comment: @RaVeN Expected Behavior - Should execute the API and return JSON response. Here its showing the file

Comment: @IleEftimov I have updated my question with public dir structure. Please let me know if anything wrong

Comment: @disha can you try renaming `public/api/` to (for example) `public/docs/` and giving it a try again?

Comment: @IleEftimov Tried. Doesn't work.

Comment: @disha Could you please add the full json response body?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne Have added JSON. Please check

Comment: @disha It's working as expected with direct call without swagger-ui right?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne Yes! But I want it to work witn swagger-ui.

Comment: @disha yh. I understood. just wanted to verify that it's only a swagger failure. And I was again confused. Is this your problem? correct me if I am wrong. You want 'api/v1/trucks.json' to return the swagger-json doc for that end-point (One you have explicitly created inside public), but instead you are getting the swagger-json doc for resource path 'api/v1/trucks'. Isn't it? Please correct me if I am wrong. I think you have probably get a conflict between public resources and swagger resources. And please add the main swagger-json doc with its access url.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne Thanks for your time! 
 Figured the problem. Please check the answer for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution. Posting so that if anyone stumbles upon can try it out.

My swagger docs configuration looked like below :

```
Swagger::Docs::Config.register_apis({
   'v1' =>{
      :api_extension_type => :json,
      :api_file_path => "public",
      :base_path => 'http://localhost:3000',
      :parent_controller => ApplicationController,
      :base_api_controller => ActionController::Base,
      :camelize_model_properties => false,
      :clean_directory => true,
      :attributes => {
            :info => {
              "title" => "Swagger Yattya",
              "description" => "Yattya api documentation",
              "termsOfServiceUrl" => "http://helloreverb.com/terms/",
              "contact" => "apiteam@wordnik.com",
              "license" => "Apache 2.0",
              "licenseUrl" => "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
        }
        }
    }
  })
```

The first line wasn't required :

```
:api_extension_type => :json
```

Removed this line from configuration and worked like a charm!